# WebDriverError: No active session with ID

Tags: javascript, selenium, tfs, protractor, jasmine2.0

My tests fail when am running them on TFS with the below error

WebDriverError: No active session with ID 
Failed: No active session with ID

The same tests pass locally - it was working fine until couple days back, but seeing this issue now

using 
protractor version - 5.4.2
Chrome driver - 2.42.exe

Comment: Can any1 Please answer the above question ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the version mismatch between the driver and browser version.

use the below version of chrome driver and corresponding browser version in you remote machine where your tests are executed

- If you are using Chrome version 74, please download ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6
- If you are using Chrome version 73, please download ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68
- If you are using Chrome version 72, please download ChromeDriver 2.46

Refer here for more info http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection

Hope it helps you

Comment: no luck the issue still exists even after changing my chromeDriver.exe version

Comment: what is the chromedriver and chrome version you are using?

Comment: chromedriver_73.0.exe 
chrome version - Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)
 Initially the first two test cases shoe up the below error and then the rest are showing the session ID error                                                                    
  Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Comment: @Adamreed Could you try with Chrome version 72 and ChromeDriver 2.46.

Comment: the issue started when i was on version 72 and chromeDriver 2.46 - Test Suites were running fine until last week with same versions